# Cannot open virtual machine in VMware

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

The VMware I used is

> VMware® Workstation 14 Pro
>
> 14.1.5 build-10950780
> The VMware I used is

VMware® Workstation 14 Pro
14.1.5 build-10950780

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 in VMware. Maybe last time I didn't shut down the virtual machine correctly, which resulted in my failure in booting it again right now.

Now when I boot the virtual machine, it stucks and flickers in a 5-second period, with the backgroud showing [The former one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0agX.png) from-time-to-time.

How do I solve the problem?Thank you for your time!!

===========================================================================
I tried @John's first method, and it flickers a silghtly new result
[The latter one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1bZL.png)
but for most of the time, it is complete dark just like the following [complete dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rP18.png)

I am tring the second method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure all virtual machines are OFF and VMware Workstation is not running.  Restart the computer, start VMware Workstation and try Ubuntu again.

This has worked for me - very similar setup as you.

Second, if the Ubuntu Machine will still not start do the following:

(1) Copy (not Move) the Ubuntu VM Folder to a new folder.

(2) Start VMware.

(3) Use Make New Machine.

(4) Point to the new folder and open then Ubuntu machine (vmdk) file.

This should repair the machine and allow you to open it.

Finally, if the above does not work, you may need to restore the Ubuntu machine from backup or make a new Virtual Machine from the Ubuntu ISO.

If needed you may be able to recover data from the VMware flat file

https://www.diskinternals.com/vmfs-recovery/recover-vm-from-flat-vmdk-the-best-solutions/

Comment: I tried both of them, but neither succeeded. For the second method, should I use a new .iso file?Should the VMware stay OFF when I copy the folder? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Best to have VMware OFF when copying the folder to ensure you can use the new folder properly.   Otherwise,  you may need to make a new machine.  See, in the command screen if you can use Ctrl Alt F1 to login

Comment: I guess I have to give up this virtual machine...Is there any chance I can restore my data in the old virtual machine?

Comment: If you cannot open it, You can possibly get the data from the flat file -- https://www.diskinternals.com/vmfs-recovery/recover-vm-from-flat-vmdk-the-best-solutions/

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I have covered all the steps. Perhaps my answer was helpful to you (so please mark it so, thanks).